# Carousel con Cards

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-carousel

Quiero hacer un carousel con Card, y que se vayan cambiado las card, tipo así:

[image: Texto]

Pero lo único que he encontrado y conseguido hacer es que solo se cambie la imagen y el texto de la card sea la misma.

He intentado meter las cards dentro del carousel pero se me descuadra todo, tengo guardado los intentos pero no tengo mucha idea y se descuadraba todo. Este es un ejemplo y partiendo de este quiero hacer el que yo necesito hacer, que no sería más que un carousel con cards, pero soy novato en esto del diseño y llevo dos días intentándolo sin éxito.

Os dejo el código por si me podéis echar una mano.

```
<div class="container py-3">
  <!-- Card Start -->
  <div class="card">
    <div class="row ">

      <div class="col-md-7 px-3">
        <div class="card-block px-6">
          <h4 class="card-title">Horizontal Card with Carousel - Bootstrap 4 </h4>
          <p class="card-text">
            The Carousel code can be replaced with an img src, no problem. The added CSS brings shadow to the card and some adjustments to the prev/next buttons and the indicators is rounded now. As in Bootstrap 3
          </p>
          <p class="card-text">Made for usage, commonly searched for. Fork, like and use it. Just move the carousel div above the col containing the text for left alignment of images</p>
          <br>
          <a href="#" class="mt-auto btn btn-primary  ">Read More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Carousel start -->
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <div id="CarouselTest" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#CarouselTest" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#CarouselTest" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#CarouselTest" data-slide-to="2"></li>

          </ol>
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img class="d-block" src="https://picsum.photos/450/300?image=1072" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img class="d-block" src="https://picsum.photos/450/300?image=855" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img class="d-block" src="https://picsum.photos/450/300?image=355" alt="">
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#CarouselTest" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#CarouselTest" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End of carousel -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End of card -->

</div>
```

Estas son las otras cards:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="card float-left">
    <div class="row ">

      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <div class="card-block">
          <!--           <h4 class="card-title">Small card</h4> -->
          <p>Wetgple text to build your own card.</p>
          <p>Change around the content for awsomenes</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Read More</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/150?image=380" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

 
    <div class="card float-right">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/150?image=641" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
          <div class="card-block">
            <!--           <h4 class="card-title">Small card</h4> -->
            <p>Copy paste the HTML and CSS.</p>
            <p>Change around the content for awsomenes</p>
            <br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm float-right">Read More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 
 <br>
<br>
```

y el css

```
.card-block {
    font-size: 1em;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
    border: none;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, .1);
    box-shadow: none;
     
}
.card {
    font-size: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5;
    border: none;
    border-radius: .28571429rem;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #d4d4d5, 0 0 0 1px #d4d4d5;
    margin-top:20px;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
    border-radius: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    background-color: #404040;
}
.carousel-indicators li {
    border-radius: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    background-color: #404040;
}
.carousel-indicators .active {
    background-color: white;
    max-width: 12px;
    margin: 0 3px;
    height: 12px;
}
.carousel-control-prev-icon {
 background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M5.25 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5-2.5-2.5 2.5-2.5-1.5-1.5z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") !important;
}

.carousel-control-next-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M2.75 0l-1.5 1.5 2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.5 1.5 4-4-4-4z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") !important;
}
 lex-direction: column;
}

.btn {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

Comment: Estoy utilizando la versión 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para que el `carousel` se visualice correctamente debes tener elementos similares entre si y un ancho bien definido en cada diapositiva, generalmente este se especifica a través de una imagen. He notado que la estructura de las `cards` en tu ejemplo no es la misma en todos los casos y esta podría ser la causa del problema.

Te dejo un ejemplos de `carousel` que utilizan `cards`. Funciona sin css extra utilizando las clases de Bootstrap.

Ejemplo con `cards` verticales:

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 4.5 css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container my-4 w-50">

        <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Diapositivas -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <div class="card h-100">
                        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyE56.png" class="card-img-top w-100 bg-dark" alt="...">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <h5 class="card-title">Card title 1</h5>
                          <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="card h-100">
                        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyE56.png" class="card-img-top w-100" alt="...">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <h5 class="card-title">Card title 2</h5>
                          <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="card h-100">
                        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyE56.png" class="card-img-top w-100" alt="...">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <h5 class="card-title">Card title 3</h5>
                          <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Controles -->
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>

    </div><!--//container-->
    
<!-- jQuery full con ajax -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap 4.5 js -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Ejemplo con `cards` horizontales:

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 4.5 css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container my-4 w-50">

    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Diapositivas -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <div class="card bg-dark text-white m-width-100">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Card title 1</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyE56.png" alt="..." width="100%">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="card bg-dark text-white m-width-100">
                    <div class="row g-0">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Card title 2</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyE56.png" alt="..." width="100%">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="card bg-dark text-white m-width-100">
                    <div class="row g-0">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Card title 3</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyE56.png" alt="..." width="100%">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Controles -->
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>

</div><!--//container-->

<!-- jQuery full con ajax -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap 4.5 js -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```